# PHP 7.4 absolute path - why is /.. ignored?

Tags: php, php-7.4

I use this to include some file

```
require_once realpath(__DIR__) . '/../anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename2.php
```

But for some reasons it seems that /.. is ignored and it triggers

> Failed opening required '/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename.php
> in /var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2/filename1.php on line 10`

where realpath(**DIR**) = /var/domains/domain.com/foldername1

What could cause /.. to be ignored, is that something new in php 7.4?

Comment: Do you have other error messages in the logs regarding this?

Comment: What’s the point of doing `realpath(__DIR__)` in the first place? `__DIR__` is already as real-pathy as it’ll ever get …

Comment: To move to the parent folder, you can also call `dirname`: `dirname(realpath(__DIR__)) . '/anotherfolder2/....`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the whole path to **realpath()** function:

`require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/../anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename2.php)`

This function changes the `dir1/dir2/../file1` into `dir1/file1`.
In your case: `/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/../anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename.php` into `/var/domains/domain.com/anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename.php`.

From documentation:

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./, /../ and extra / characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: `realpath()`, while redundant here, can neither be the problem nor the solution. It just gets a canonical path. It doesn't *change* the location it points to.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your statement that `realpath(__DIR__)` is `'/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1'` is incorrect.

Your error message includes the file path where the error happened:

> ... in /var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2/filename1.php on line 10

So we know that `__FILE__` will be `'/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2/filename1.php'`, and `__DIR__` will be `'/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2'`.

`realpath` is unlikely to change that, so we have:

```
require_once '/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2' . '/../anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename2.php'
```

The `..` will strip out the first `anotherfolder2` giving:

```
require_once '/var/domains/domain.com/foldername1/anotherfolder2/anotherfolder3/filename2.php'
```

Which is the file path the error message says it can't find.